# difference in output of bash script

Tags: bash

I have saved following command in a script called dir

```
ls -la | egrep '^d'
```

i saved the file dir under  my home/bin directory, which also happens to be in my PATH variable. If i execute dir command from any other directory, it has the effect of a simple ls, but  if i copy this file into any folder and then run dir, i get the correct output.

what needs to be done, so that i can run the above script by simply typing dir and it shows me the correct result?

UPDATE: the above works correctly on mac os x, but does not work correctly under linux as explained above.

Comment: In linux you can make an alias under your shell

Comment: `ls -la */` will have the same affect without needing grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because there already is a command named dir, and it's got priority over your script. Try giving it a name that is not reserved.

Comment: I'm glad. Accept the answer then meaby?

Comment: done, stackoverflow will not let me accept till 10 minutes after the  post.